# Using ST_split to split a line feature using nearby points

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, line, splitting

I have a line shapefile and a point shapefile, and

- the line has just one segment

[image]

and its attribute table,

[image]

- the point shapefile has points near the line above, not on it

[image]

and the close look,

[image]

**I want to use ST_split to split this line at locations which are nearest to the points** **I want to get the original line with more segments(because being split).** For example, find the location on the line, which is the nearest to the point, and split the line at this location(star).

[image]

I loaded this line shapefile into PostGIS and here's my SQL code in PostgreSQL,

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Split(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 247907.60 2746404.62, 200    200, 400 400)'),
       ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 247907.60 2746404.62, 200 200, 400 400)'), 0.2)))
```

And I checked the table of this line, it wasn't being splited.

Where did I make mistakes？ I am new to use ST_split, please give me any suggestion, thanks.

I am using QGIS 2.2, PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostGIS 2.0.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

Update#1

@simplexio, I used your code,

```
select ST_Line_SubString(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 247907.60 2746404.62, 200 200, 400 400)'), 0 , 0.200 ) as geom into split_line ;
```

and got a new table named split_line,

[image]

But as I used the following code you posted,

```
SELECT ST_Line_SubString(line, 0, ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.line, p.point)) as from_start_geom,
       ST_Line_SubString(l.line,ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.line, p.point), 1) to_end_geom, l.line_id, p.point_id FROM lines l , points p 
WHERE l.line_id = 1 , p.point_id = 1
```

I got a syntax error,

[image]

How to fix this and move on？ And where should I assign the line I want to split as input of st_split？

Comment: syntax error fix, change , from where clause to AND

Comment: I change the comma in this line:"WHERE l.line_id = 1 , p.point_id = 1" to AND, but got another error:LINE 3:  l.line_id, p.point_id FROM lines l , points p , relation "lines" doesn't exist.

Comment: FROM clause line means line table, points means point table. WHERE l.line_id points to line table and lines_id point to id column. query should be modified to suit your need , it only shows basic idea how you can extract substring from specific line using specific point.

Answer (score 7):

As has been suggested earlier and [in the ST_Split documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html), you must first snap your line to the points and then call ST_Split.

If you are like me, an example is worth more than words:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS split;
CREATE TABLE split AS(
SELECT
    (ST_Dump(ST_Split(ST_Snap(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, 0.00001),b.the_geom))).geom
FROM 
    line_table a
JOIN 
    point_table b 
ON 
    ST_DWithin(b.the_geom, a.wkb_geometry, "Your Tolerance to Search for Lines (e.g., a number)")
);
```

Comment: Why you are snapping line to point instead point to line? Wouldn't this move line to location of point?

Answer (score 1):

Another method to split lines:

```
create table in_edges_split as
select a.id, (st_dump(st_split(st_segmentize(a.geom,1),st_union(b.geom)))).geom as geom 
from in_edges a, in_points b where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) group by a.id;
```

Or if you need to snap your points to the lines first:

```
create table in_edges_split as
select a.id, (st_dump(st_split(st_segmentize(a.geom,1),st_union(b.geom)))).geom as geom 
from in_edges a, 
(select st_snap(d.geom,c.geom,0.00000001) as geom from in_edges c, in_points d) b 
group by a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get you code to work and far as i can see it should work, maybe there is some problem with ST_Split and tolerance. You can use following code :

```
select ST_Line_SubString(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 247907.60 2746404.62, 200 200, 400 400)'), 0 , 0.200 ) as geom into split_line ;
```

Now you have table (split_line) which has one colum(geom) which has lines from 0 to 0.2 (max is 1).
locating fraction is done using ST_Line_Locate_Point(line,geom) return float, st_Line_SubString(line, from,to) return always linestrings, so it's easier to handle those rather than geometrycollections which you need to "open" and extract only lines

```
 SELECT ST_Line_SubString(line, 0, ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.line, p.point)) as from_start_geom,
    ST_Line_SubString(l.line,ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.line, p.point), 1) to_end_geom,
 l.line_id, p.point_id FROM lines l , points p 
WHERE l.line_id = 1 AND p.point_id = 1
```

see: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2192
it seems that when using st_split you need to use st_snap to snap point on to line. if possible i would prefer linear referencing methods because they are more mature code.