# Join point attributes to lines

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, explode

I'm working in QGIS with two shapefiles: point and line. Points mark nodes of the lines, and each of them have their own attributes. Lines are related to an attribute table too. The goal is, once the lines are exploded between nodes, to join ONE point attributes to each new line section.
How can I join point attributes to each line section?
(better not using any plugins, so I still cannot download them)

Answer (score 2):

Try "join attributes by location".

Problem is, that the lines by definition have two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any plugins... then only tool I can think of is a **Virtual Layer**.

Given:

- You have one `segments` layer (exploded line, and saved as a new line shapefile)
- You also have one `points` layer. And the data you want to extract is stored in the `your_data` field of `points` layer.

(1) Go to menu `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`.

(2) Click on `[Import]` and select your `segments` and `points` layers.

(3) In the Query window, give an expression:

```
SELECT segments.*, points.your_data
  FROM segments, points
 WHERE st_intersects(st_buffer(st_startpoint(segments.geometry), 10), points.geometry)=1
```

Additional note -

- In the above example there is a `st_buffer(..., 10)` which is a tolerance radius `(10m)` between your points and nodes of linestring.
- If the points are located at the exactly same as nodes,  `st_intersects(st_startpoint(segments.geometry), points.geometry)=1` would work just fine.
- (and you may want to use `st_endpoint` rather than `st_startpoint`).

Comment: See the answer "Map1" at this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101459/using-st-split-to-split-a-line-feature-using-nearby-points I think he'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Cyril um... I disagree to recommend PostGIS. Sergi's working environment does not allow downloading plugins, possibility of setting up PostGIS would be even less.

Comment: What prevents the user to join the QGIS, PostgreSQL/PostGIS and solved using these tools and analytical tasks?

Comment: @Cyril If you think PostGIS is the right way to achieve solution, you can post it as your answer. We can support asker in various approaches. Only thing prevents the user to use any tool is their IT environment, not us.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I am using ArcGIS to solve this problem. Which tool may I use now?