# Using PostGIS to split linestrings with points

Tags: postgis, splitting

I would like to cut my line network using points that I have created using ST_LineInterpolatePoint, however, when I use the query created by @geozelot from a similar question I get a generally unsplit lines table back.

The following are the steps I am performing:

Step 1: Create a points table that I will use as a blade to cut my linestrings.

```
CREATE TABLE point_table AS ( 
  SELECT n,
         ST_LineInterpolatePoint(l.geom, LEAST(n*(100/ST_Length(l.geom)), 1.0))::GEOMETRY(POINT, 3005) AS geom
  FROM   public.line l
  CROSS JOIN
         Generate_Series(0, CEIL(ST_Length(l.geom)/100)::INT) AS n
);
```

Step 2: Split linestring with points_table as a blade.

```
CREATE TABLE split_line AS
    SELECT a.id,
           (ST_Dump(ST_Split(
             a.geom,
             (SELECT ST_Collect(b.geom) AS geom FROM public.point_table AS b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
           )))).geom
    FROM   public.line AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.id, a.geom
    FROM   public.line AS a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   public.point_table AS b
      WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
    );
```

Comment: I think you are missing the snapping. Due to rounding errors your points don't have to necessarily lie directly on top of your lines. Have a look at this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129613/6253

Comment: @TimothyDalton That does split the lines (from 423 to 21,000 features), but they are still not separate line segments and cannot see the results in qgis.  I select a line and the whole line segment is selected instead of all the segments between the points.  The ST_Dump doesn't seem to be exploding the lines.  I even tried multipart to singlepart in qgis and still the same.